# SSL pages and non secure content in an iframe?

Tags: facebook, iframe, ssl

Facebook and their app partners seem to achieve this.

If you look at the Farmville URL you can see it's serving over SSL: https://apps.facebook.com/onthefarm/?ref=ts

Facebook then iframe in the content from the game provider (Zynga) using another SSL iframe src. But then you see ad code called via non-secure external JS calls.

What are the rules/techniques concerning delivery of non secure page elements (Flash, images etc) without mixed content warnings in iframes when the top level page is serving over SSL?

SSL Page (Facebook) > SSL iFrame (App Provider) > Non-SSL iFrame (App Provider) > HTTP image/Script call?

Answer (score -1):

You can't really use a custom app page without using SSL. But if you are looking for a free alternative you can use facebook app provides like http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook

You can even use dropbox as an free alternative if you wanna host your iFrame fan page.

For a paid and best solution, you would need an web hosting and a domain with dedicated IP and SSL installed on it.

Comment: Thanks but I am not looking to build an app. I advertise via some of the apps and am asking how Facebook and the app providers can (demonstrably) have a secure Facebook.com URL, with a secure app Iframe URL, serve my ads without mixed content warnings. It's happening today.